# Video pop up trigger event based on URL parameter DRY

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to clean up this code. how can I make this DRY? I am repeating a lot of code.

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
return decodeURI(
    (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
);}

if(getURLParameter('video1')==1){ $(".urlVid1").trigger('click'); }

if(getURLParameter('video2')==1){ $(".urlVid2").trigger('click'); }

if(getURLParameter('video3')==1){ $(".urlVid3").trigger('click'); }

if(getURLParameter('video4')==1){ $(".urlVid4").trigger('click'); }
```

Comment: sorry.. hopefully this makes more sense.

Comment: It's not that it didn't make sense.  Questions that appear to ask for opinions are hard for users to know what the "right" answer is, because it's subjective.  Which is why one of the close reasons for questions is asking for opinions. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least a couple ways you could do this.  You could use the index of a loop, or explicitly list out the keys you want to consider.

```js
function getURLParameter(name) {
  return decodeURI(
    (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search) || [, null])[1]
  );
}

//using just the number
[1, 2, 3, 4].forEach(function(key){
  if (getURLParameter('video'+ key) === 1) {
    $('.urlVid'+ key).trigger('click');
  }
});

//explicitly giving the keys
[
  { video: 'video1', url: '.urlVid1' }
  , { video: 'video2', url: '.urlVid2' }
].forEach(function(pair){
  if (getURLParameter(pair.video) === 1) {
    $(pair.url).trigger('click');
  }
});
```